# Is two pointer problem same as sliding window

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I was wondering about the significant difference between
'sliding window' and 'two pointer' problem.

It is giving me a hard time to differentiate between the two.

Answer (score 78):

Sliding window algorithms can be implemented with a single pointer and a variable for window size. Typically we use all of the elements within the window for the problem (for eg - sum of all elements in the window).

Two pointer technique is quite similar but we usually compare the value at the two pointers instead of all the elements between the pointers.

Two pointers can also have variations like fast-slow pointer.

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: "Two pointer technique is quite similar but we usually compare the value at the two pointers instead of all the elements between the pointers."

That was my main confusion point .Thank u

Comment: Cool, if you can mark it as the answer/upvote that will be great!

Comment: great explanation

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, the sliding window algorithm focuses on managing a window size (subarray or substring) in a larger data structure for efficient computations,

while the two pointers algorithm relies on using two points, usually indexes to traverse and compare elements in a sequence in a data structure eg arrays or strings.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in 2 pointer, both the pointers are kept at the extreme ends of the array. And pointers are updated to move towards each other. Eg LeetCode problems: Valid Palidrome, 2 sum, 3 sum, container with most water.

In sliding window, generally, l is initialized as 0 and r is initialized as l+1. And they are updated to move in the same direction. Eg problem: Best time to buy and sell stock

Answer (score -1):

Main Difference(Short): In sliding window techniques, we care about each element within the window as we analyze contiguous subsets of the iterable. In contrast, the two-pointer technique focuses on meeting conditions simultaneously for both pointers within the iterable, disregarding the elements between them.

Sliding window techniques are typically used when the problem requires the consideration of a contiguous subset of elements from an ordered iterable, such as a list or array. Each element within this subset, often referred to as a 'window', carries some significance for the problem, and operations like calculating the sum of its elements are commonly performed. This technique involves iteratively shifting the window across the iterable, adjusting its size as needed to analyze different subsets efficiently.

On the other hand, the two-pointer technique involves the movement of two pointers within the iterable, often with the objective of meeting a certain condition or constraint simultaneously with both pointers. Unlike the sliding window approach, the focus here is not on the elements between the pointers but rather on the conditions met by the elements pointed to. This technique is particularly useful for tasks like searching for pairs of elements that satisfy a specific criterion or comparing elements at different positions within the iterable.

Also, found similar question being asked here:
[What is the difference of Two pointers pattern and slide window pattern in Algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64535478/what-is-the-difference-of-two-pointers-pattern-and-slide-window-pattern-in-algor/)