# What is the difference of Two pointers pattern and slide window pattern in Algorithms?

Tags: algorithm

As I know both mentioned patterns use two pointers and most of the time they solve in O(N) time.
are they both the same pattern with different name? I need a comparison between them to better understand them.

Answer (score 0):

Sliding window usually has predefined size ("window size K"), while distance between two pointers changes during traversal.

Also note that these approaches in general don't guarantee O(N) time because treatment for every step might take some time.

Answer (score 0):

Main Difference(Short): In sliding window techniques, we care about each element within the window as we analyze contiguous subsets of the iterable. In contrast, the two-pointer technique focuses on meeting conditions simultaneously for both pointers within the iterable, disregarding the elements between them.

Sliding window techniques are typically used when the problem requires the consideration of a contiguous subset of elements from an ordered iterable, such as a list or array. Each element within this subset, often referred to as a 'window', carries some significance for the problem, and operations like calculating the sum of its elements are commonly performed. This technique involves iteratively shifting the window across the iterable, adjusting its size as needed to analyze different subsets efficiently.

On the other hand, the two-pointer technique involves the movement of two pointers within the iterable, often with the objective of meeting a certain condition or constraint simultaneously with both pointers. Unlike the sliding window approach, the focus here is not on the elements between the pointers but rather on the conditions met by the elements pointed to. This technique is particularly useful for tasks like searching for pairs of elements that satisfy a specific criterion or comparing elements at different positions within the iterable.

Also, found similar question being asked here:
[Is two pointer problem same as sliding window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64078162/is-two-pointer-problem-same-as-sliding-window)